# Handling Duplicate Fields From Separate Types in Kibana

Tags: kibana, kibana-4

I am currently using Kibana 4, and I'm having issues creating visualizations for specific types. My ElasticSearch index looks something like this:

```
{
    "school_data": {
        "mappings": {
            "teacher": {
                "properties": {
                    "Name": {
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "School": {
                        "type": "string"
                    }
                }
            },
            "student": {
                "properties": {
                    "Name": {
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "School": {
                        "type": "string"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

where the index is `school_data` and the two types are `teacher` and `student`. I can load the index `school_data` into Kibana, but the only fields I can see for this index are `Name` and `School`. Is there a way to make a visualization that is specific to just one of these types? i.e. Could I make a visualization that shows me the counts of the top 20 distinct `teacher` names?

Comment: If you do a search with `_type: teacher` in the search bar, does it work? I think it should work

Comment: @Pigueiras Based on minimal testing, it seems like that's going to work. I'm running into another issue that is out of my scope, but I'm hoping the issue is resolved by tomorrow so I can give you a definitive 'yes' or 'no'. If it does work, I'll gladly accept your answer if you make one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to select the documents of the type you need by putting in the search bar `_type: "<your_type>"`. This search will only select the documents with that specific type. This will allow you to do a visualization that shows the top 20 counts of `<your_type>`.